# NullPointerException while accessing nested objects of Root object in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, junit

I am writing test cases using Mockito (not powermock) for my Hibernate's Predicate class.

My method is as follows-

```
buildXYZQuery(Root<?> root, Filter filter, CriteriaBuilder cb, Predicate where, String Login) {
    Predicate predicate1 = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("object1")), "VALUE1");
    Predicate predicate2 = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("object1")), "VALUE1");
    Predicate predicate3 = cb.like(cb.upper(root.get("object1").get("object2").get("DataMember_Of_Object2_Returning_String_Value")), "VALUE1");
    where = cb.and(predicate1, predicate2, predicate3);
    return where;
}
```

for this method, I am trying to write junit test case as-

```
  public class HibPaginationTest {
      @InjectMocks
      HibPagination pagn = new HibPagination();

      Root root = new Root() {
         @override
         public EntityType getModel() { return null; }

         @override
         public Path get(String s) { return null; }
         .....
         .....

         //  all methods from javax.persistence.criteria.Root interface

      };
      
      Predicate predicate = new Predicate() {
        // all methods from javax.persistence....Predicate
      };

      CriteriaBuilder cb = new CriteriaBuilder() {
      .......
      };

      @Test
      public void buildXYZQueryTest() {
          pagn.buildXYZQuery(root, filter, cb, where, "test_user");
      }
  }
```

Here, my test case fails with NPE when it tries to execute for Predicate 3 that is for accessing nested objects (root.get().get().get()). How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: how you are defining root object ?

Comment: @NareshJ Hi Naresh, I have edit my query with more details to better understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `root` object and do the following by returning each object exactly the same type. for example of `obj_1` from class `Target` you can mock it, then do mock to `obj_2` until finishing the calling chain.

```
when(root.get()).thenReturn(obj_1);
when(obj_1.get()).thenReturn(obj_2);
when(obj_2.get()).thenReturn(obj_3);
```

This will solve the solution, this in case `root` object is complex you mock it, but if it's kind of `pojo` you can fill it with the data

Comment: My Bad, instead of object_3, I want to return string value which is the return type of one of field from Object2. It expects to return javax.persistance.criteria.Path in last when ..Return in place of obj3. I tried to override it to return String anyhow but I could not get success.

Comment: @AniruddhDwivedi then you can mock Object2 and return dummy string to avoid NLP in get calls

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Here is the solution.

```
when(root.get("object1")).thenReturn(path);
```

And path is just mock of Path

```
@Mock
Path path;
```